# Why are months one less than the selected value when using DatePickerDialog in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date, simpledateformat

I'm developing an Android app in Kotlin, and I'm using the **DatePickerDialog** to allow the user to select a date. However, I've noticed that when the user selects a month, the value passed to the OnDateSetListener callback is one less than the actual selected value.

For example, if I select the date *15/December/2022*, the callback will receive selectedMonth as 11 instead of 12. Similarly, if I select *3/January/2023*, the callback will receive selectedMonth as 12 instead of 1.  For February it is 1.

Here's the relevant code I'm using:

```
fun pickDate() {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    DatePickerDialog(this,
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay ->
            val selectedDate = "$selectedDay/$selectedMonth/$selectedYear"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
            val formattedDate = sdf.format(sdf.parse(selectedDate))
            dateText?.text = formattedDate.toString()
        },
        year,
        month,
        day
    ).show()
}
```

As you can see, I'm formatting the selected date as a string using the selectedDay, selectedMonth, and selectedYear values passed to the callback. However, since the selectedMonth value is one less than the actual selected value, the resulting string is incorrect.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I can fix it so that the displayed date is correct?
Thanks in advance for any help

I got some answers from some site that Month here starts from 0. It it was true January should be 0 not 12.

Comment: BTW `Calendar.JANUARY == 0` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY))... despite `Calendar`, `Date`, and similar were outdated with Java 8  and replaced by classes from the `java.time` package (no idea about `DatePickerDialog`)

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, neither here nor anywhere at all.That class was notoriously troublesome and is long outdated. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Also for conversion from numbers to a date-time object don’t go through building a string and parsing it back. Your problem comes from your date picker confusingly using 0-based months 0 = January through 11 = December. So you need `LocalDate.of(selectedYear, selectedMonth + 1, selectedDay)`. Format the `LocalDate` using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: The `Calendar` API is absolutely terrible for reasons like this.  Never use it.

Answer (score -1):

if you look at the official doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

month value goes from 0 to 11 so it is normal

it is said to be compatible with java.util.Calendar, maybe you are using an incompatible calendar

Comment: Then why January shows as 12? It should be 0

Comment: are you using the java.util.Calendar class ?

Comment: *Then why January shows as 12? It should be 0*. Because `SimpleDateFormat` knows that there is no month 0. So it interprets month 0 as month 12 in the previous year. Yes, confusing indeed. Don’t use that class.